# command 'scala' not found after set up by coursier

Tags: linux, scala, ubuntu, path, coursier

I use [coursier](https://get-coursier.io/docs/cli-installation) to set up the environment of Scala using command `./cs setup` in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It was said that all the requirements were installed. However, when I use command `scala -version` to check whether the installation succeeded, it shown that `Command 'scala' not found`. [The result of command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ2sV.png). Reboot didn't work. So please help me to slove this problem! Thanks!

Information: An ECS with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, user is not the root.

Comment: Make sure you have something like this: `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/share/coursier/bin"` in either your `.bashrc` or `.profile` files.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you for your suggestion and sorry for my replying late. I think it is helpful and I will try later if I rebuild my environment.

Comment: Might have to wait for some time before changes are reflected. In my case(Windows 10 pro) I checked around for 15-20 min and then started manual installation. But after downloading openJDK(1st step for manual installation) when I tried to check the environment PATH it had the coursier path added to it and 'scala' command also worked.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, it looks like coursier is adding scala bin path to the `~/.profile` file using double quotations:

```bash
# >>> coursier install directory >>>
export PATH="$PATH:/home/username/.local/share/coursier/bin"
# <<< coursier install directory <<<
```

So I removed the double quotations and it worked fine for me

```bash
# >>> coursier install directory >>>
export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/.local/share/coursier/bin
# <<< coursier install directory <<<
```

You can run this command in your terminal after updating the profile file, so the new changes takes effect immediately in your terminal with no need to log out or open a new terminal tab.

```bash
source ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, coursier did modify my `.bash_profile` to include:

```
# >>> coursier install directory >>>
export PATH="$PATH:/home/james/.local/share/coursier/bin"
# <<< coursier install directory <<<
```

But that didn't work for me.

I had to edit the `.bashrc` and on the last line add:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/share/coursier/bin"
```

You will have to run `bash` or logout and back in for it to take effect.

Comment: Yes! And thank you for your help. I gave up fixing it since I just want to run Chisel projects. It needs `sbt` and `JVM` at all and Courier is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For those on OSX I found that I had to change the directory that coursier had automatically added to the PATH in my .bash_profile:

`export PATH="$PATH:/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Coursier/bin"`

to

`export PATH="$PATH:/Users/username/Library/Application\ Support/Coursier/bin"`

Basically add the backslash in. Then run `source .bash_profile` to reload the profile.